# How to add an arbitrary file to the sdcard DOS partition using yocto

Tags: yocto

Is it possible to add an arbitrary file to the sdcard DOS partition using Yocto?

The aim is to then copy this file to another location from within u-boot using another custom u-boot command. The custom u-boot command is already in place. This will basically copy this arbitrary file over SPI to another device.

I know this would be trivial to accomplish from Linux user space, but I have a design constraint such that this file is to be copied from u-boot space.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of helping others who may stumble at the same hurdle...

#### In your meta-`<COMPANY-LAYER>` :

1. Create a `classes` directory
2. Within this directory create a new `bbclass` file which inherits from the current `bbclass` file used to create your image
3. Override `BOOT_SPACE` to an appropriate size
4. Override the appropriate `generate_*_sdcard()` function to include a step that copies the additional files into `boot.img`, the new files will have been written to `${DEPLOY_DIR}` and can be copied from there
5. In your image-recipe directory add a subdirectory `files` and within this place your additional files
6. Add the new file names to the recipe `SRC_URI` list, these will end up in `$(DEPLOY_DIR}`, (see point 4)
7. In your `<image>.bb` file inherit from your new bbclass file, make sure this inherit line appears after any other inherit-image line

Now generate your image as per usual and inspect the resulting sdcard image. You should firstly see that the MSDOS partition size has increased to the new size specified with `BOOT_SPACE` and secondly the new files themselves along side zImage and `*.dtb`.